# Prevent file upload from starting in filepond

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filepond

Is it possible to prevent the upload of a file from starting in `filepond` from client-side Js? (E.g. if a text input is not filled).

Even if the upload was started manually by clicking on a button (included in filepond input), I still don't have control on whether the upload should carry on.

I know there's a way to implement that by creating a validation plugin (returning a promise), but I thought there was an easier way to do it (I can't find any relevant method/function in the docs).

**Edit:**

I found a way to do it by creating a plugin (very similar to `filepond-plugin-file-validate-size`), but the `LOAD_FILE` event isn't the one I'm looking for. Is there another event that's triggered after the file has been added and the user has clicked on the submit button (on the right)?